# Macro to set pivot field based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how can I write my macro to set my pivot filter based on a cell value

A1=today()

I want to set my pivot filter to automatically select the filter based on cell A1 when I run the macro. Can someone teach me the right code to do this?

Comment: What research have you tried and what didn't work? 
 Here is a link that may help if you are stuck with researching: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/08/16/sync-pivots-from-dropdown/

Comment: Have you tried using the "Record a Macro" option, setting the filter manually, the hitting "Stop Recording" and then adjusting the code it writes for you?

Comment: Yes I've tried recording but I can't get the recorder to change the pivot filter based on cell A1. Any idea how I can do so?

Comment: Either by running a `For Each` on the  `PivotItems` and comparing each `.Caption` to A1, or by using `PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=Range("A1").Value`